# Change SUMIF and CHANGIF formulas so that filtered data only gets calculated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have these formulas that calculate data from another tab's table, but if I filter data out of the table, my formulas still calculate the filtered out data. I'm pretty new to excel, but I've read a few forums on using SUMPRODUCT to get the results I want but not sure how to do it. Below I have posted a few formulas. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

=COUNTIF(USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,465)

=SUMIF(USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465",USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000)-SUMIFS(USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000,USSW1!$M$7:$M$25000,"FP",USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465")

=COUNTIFS(USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465",USSW1!$M$7:$M$25000,"FP")

=SUMIF(USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465",USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000)-SUMIFS(USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000,USSW1!$M$7:$M$25000,"CA",USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465")-SUMIFS(USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000,USSW1!$M$7:$M$25000,"CF",USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465")

=SUMIF(USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465",USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000)
Quote ReplyReport

Comment: So use SUMIFS() & countifs() with the filtering criteria added - that way the results will match what you get from filtering.

Comment: The formulas are a lot simpler if you can add another column to the source data table using SUBTOTAL so that it returns 1 for visible rows and 0 for hidden. Then you just include  that as another criterion. Also note your SUMIFS appear overly complicated since you can exclude data too - eg: `=SUMIFS(USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000,USSW1!$M$7:$M$25000,"<>FP",USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465")` rather than `=SUMIF(USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465",USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000)-SUMIFS(USSW1!$O$7:$O$25000,USSW1!$M$7:$M$25000,"FP",USSW1!$V$7:$V$25000,"465")`

Comment: Would it be possible without having to add another column? I changed all my formulas to work the same but with sumproduct.